# Strange Segmentation Fault in Heap Implementation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, heap, priority-queue

Given below is a driver program I have written for using my own implementation of a heap.

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Heap.h"

int main(){
        Heap h(30);
        h.insert(1);
        h.insert(3);
        h.insert(5);
        h.insert(6);
        h.insert(5);
        h.insert(8);

        h.display();
        std::cout<<h.extractMin();    // Statement 1
        h.display();
        }
```

This gives the desired result as:

```
========= Heap Contents =========
1   3   5   6   5   8   
1
========= Heap Contents =========
3   6   5   8   5
```

However, if I change the `statement 1` to:

```
   std::cout<<"Min: "<<h.extractMin();
```

the code starts giving a Segmentation fault. Again, if I change the `statement 1` to

```
int z = h.extractMin();
```

the code still gives a Segmentation fault. This tempted me to see if I am doing something wrong in `extractMin()`. Below is my definition of `extractMin()`:

```
int Heap::extractMin()
{
    int min = this -> arr[0];
    this -> arr[0] = this -> arr[heapSize];

    heapSize -= 1;
    heapify(0);

    return min;
}
```

And just for completeness's sake below is my definition for `heapify()`:

```
void Heap::heapify(int index){
        if(index > this -> heapSize)
                return;

        int smallest = index;
        int l = leftChild(index);
        int r = rightChild(index);

        if(l <= heapSize && arr[l] < arr[index])
                smallest = l;
        if(r <= heapSize && arr[r] < smallest)
                smallest = r;

        if(smallest != index){
                arr[smallest] = arr[smallest] ^ arr[index];
                arr[index] = arr[smallest] ^ arr[index];
                arr[smallest] = arr[smallest] ^ arr[index];
                heapify(smallest);
                }
        }
```

Any idea what's going on? I am unable to understand the reason behind segmentation fault. Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Thank you!

### Addition 1:

This happens for `h.getHeapSize()` and `h.getArrSize()` as well, which makes me think that the problem lies in something else and not in the functions.

### Addition 2:

The entire code goes below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

class Heap{
    private:
        int* arr;
        int size;
        int heapSize;
    public:
        Heap(int = 8); 
        Heap(int*, int size);
        int* initArr(int size);
        void setSize(int);
        int getSize();
        int getHeapSize();
        void setHeapSize(int);
        int leftChild(int);
        int rightChild(int);
        int parent(int);
        void heapify(int);
        void buildHeap();
        void insert(int);
        int extractMin();
        void display() const;
    };

Heap::Heap(int size){
    initArr(size);
    this -> size = size;
    this -> heapSize = -1;
    }

Heap::Heap(int* arr, int size){
    this -> arr = arr;
    this -> size = size;
    this -> heapSize = size - 1;
    buildHeap();
    }

int* Heap::initArr(int size){
    int* arr = new int[size];
    return arr;
    }

void Heap::setSize(int size){
    if(size > this -> heapSize)
        this -> size = size;
    }

int Heap::getSize(){
    return this -> size;
    }

void Heap::setHeapSize(int heapSize){
    this -> heapSize = heapSize;
    }

int Heap::getHeapSize(){
    return this -> heapSize;
    }

int Heap::leftChild(int index){
    return 2*index + 1;
    }

int Heap::rightChild(int index){
    return 2*index + 2;
    }

int Heap::parent(int index){
    return ceil(index >> 1) - 1;
    }

void Heap::heapify(int index){
    if(index > this -> heapSize)
        return;

    int smallest = index;
    int l = leftChild(index);
    int r = rightChild(index);

    if(l <= heapSize && arr[l] < arr[index])
        smallest = l;
    if(r <= heapSize && arr[r] < smallest)
        smallest = r;

    if(smallest != index){
        arr[smallest] = arr[smallest] ^ arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[smallest] ^ arr[index];
        arr[smallest] = arr[smallest] ^ arr[index];
        heapify(smallest);
        }
    }

void Heap::buildHeap(){
    for(int i = heapSize/2 - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        heapify(i);
    }

void Heap::insert(int val){
    heapSize += 1;
    int loc = heapSize;

    arr[heapSize] = val;
    int p;

    while((p = arr[parent(heapSize)]) > val){   
        arr[loc] = arr[p] ^ arr[loc];
        arr[p] = arr[p] ^ arr[loc];
        arr[loc] = arr[p] ^ arr[loc];
        }
    }

int Heap::extractMin(){
    //int temp = arr[0];
    //arr[0] = arr[heapSize];
    //arr[heapSize] = temp;

    int min = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[heapSize];

    heapSize -= 1;
    heapify(0);

    //return arr[heapSize + 1];
    return min;
    }

void Heap::display() const{
    std::cout<<"\n========= Heap Contents =========\n";
    for(int i = 0; i <= heapSize; i++)
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<'\t';
    std::cout<<'\n';
    }
```

Comment: Shall we assume `heapSize` accounts for the fact that arrays in C/C++ are *zero-based*, because if it doesn't, this: `this -> arr[heapSize]` is a significant problem. (and lose the xor swap. It adds *nothing* but clutter to the code. either use a temp or use `std::swap`).

Comment: Yes. I have taken care of that.
And about XOR swap, I was just checking it, not a big deal. Thanks anyways!

Comment: So `heapSize` is actually "the heap size less-one". Interesting...

Comment: I'd say heapSize is to blame, but diagnosing that would need a minimal working example.

Comment: Yeah. It's funny you say **"just for completeness's sake"** and subsequently omit 40% of the relevant code

Comment: Post `Heap.h` and `Heap.cpp` in their entirety. If it isn't already obvious the answer is in one/both of them. You're seg-fault is happening more than likely because you're writing to memory that you don't own, and in the process seeing **undefined behavior** as a result. Once you cross that line you can't trust *anything* (like `h.getHeapSize()` faulting, which I submit is a red herring triggered by the *real* problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous problems.

First, your constructor that takes an `int` parameter doesn't initialize the `arr` member, it allocates memory and assigns it to a local pointer variable, which it returns but you just ignore the return value.
You have to store it in the member variable (it's usually a very bad idea to name local variables the same as members.)

Once you fix that: during the first insertion, `h.insert(1);`, `parent(heapSize)` is -1.
Since you use that to index in the array, the program has undefined behaviour and all bets are off; the program isn't a valid C++ program.

There might be other problems as well, but those are the most obvious.

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted here, improper handling of the heap size is to blame. All test involving `heapSize` do not seem to account for zero based accessing. You should really change this, as it leads to a lot of unlogical consequences: Does heapSize get initialized to `-1`?

As for debugging:

- Leisurely add more null and boundary checks (not only to `heapSize` but also to 0)
- Try reducing the test set (does it crash with one item?) and try to trace the control flow by hand or by using gdb

**EDIT**

The bug is in `parent()`. Try the debugging tips.

Comment: OKay. I'll do that. And yes, `heapSize` is initialised to `-1`. I've posted the complete code now.